# FromJson and ToJson for my own structure

Tags: json, rust

I can't make my struct encodable/decodable:

```
enum MyEnum {
  Enum1,
  Enum2,
  Enum3,
}

#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]
pub struct MyStruct {
  val1: MyEnum,
  val2: i32,
  val3 : BTreeMap<i64, Json>,
}
```

The errors are:

```
the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable` is not implemented for the type `rustc_serialize::json::Json`
the trait `rustc_serialize::serialize::Decodable` is not implemented for the type `rustc_serialize::json::MyEnum`
```

I'm confused of what I need to implement?

Instead of `RustcEncodable` I need to implement `ToJson#to_json`. 
But what about `RustcDecodable`? There's no trait `FromJson#from_json`

In the documentation it says `rustc_serialize::Decodable/Encodable` 
But would I need `Decodable` if there's `ToJson#to_json`?

Anyway, the question is how to make my own struct encodable to and decodable from JSON?

Comment: Note that the Rust style is 4-space indents.

Comment: Could you explain why you did not also annotate `MyEnum` with `#[derive(RustcDecodable, RustcEncodable)]`? Could you also explain why you want to have the field `val3: BTreeMap<i64, Json>`, specifically what that might represent?

Comment: @Shepmaster, 1) Ok 2) no, I can't explain. I want just to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you shouldn't use rustc_serialize. It is not well designed and slow, only very few formats are supported. [Serde](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde) is the recommended crate for serialization and deserialization. It works on on both stable and nightly.

Comment: It doesn't look ridiculous and awfully difficult to understand in the code example in the [repo](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde)... Maybe you have tried an older version with poor ergonomics?

Comment: Using serde is actually very simple. Writing a lib to support another format requires writing a lot of code but everything is really needed and serde feels well designed.